# stack overflow exception while getting height of binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a simple Binary Tree, then add several integers to the tree and finally print out the height of the tree. Although I seem to be getting a stack overflow exception when calling the BinaryTree height() method. Can anyone tell me why? Please advise if I have implemented something incorrectly as this is my first time working with Binary Trees (I have looked over a few tutorials and came up with this code)

TreeNode.cpp

```
#include "TreeNode.h"


TreeNode::TreeNode(int theData)
{
    theData = value;
}
```

BinaryTree.cpp

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

void BinaryTree::add(int data)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        add(root,data);
    }
    else {
        root = new TreeNode(data);
        root->value = data;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
}

int BinaryTree::height()
{
    return height(root);
}



void BinaryTree::add(TreeNode * toAdd, int key)
{
    if (key < toAdd->value) {
        if (toAdd->left != NULL) {
            add(toAdd->left, key);
        }
        else {
            toAdd->left = new TreeNode(key);
            toAdd->left->value = key;
            toAdd->left->left = NULL;
            toAdd->left->right = NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (toAdd->right != NULL) {
            add(toAdd->right, key);
        }
        else {
            toAdd->right = new TreeNode(key);
            toAdd->right->value = key;
            toAdd->right->left = NULL;
            toAdd->right->right = NULL;
        }
    }

}

int BinaryTree::height(TreeNode *node)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {

        int leftSide = height(root->left);
        int rightSide = height(root->right);
        int total = leftSide + rightSide;
        return total;
    }

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    BinaryTree *tree = new BinaryTree();

    tree->add(10);
    tree->add(12);
    tree->add(14);
    tree->add(15);
    tree->add(123);
    tree->add(14);
    tree->add(12);
    tree->add(15);

    tree->height();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height` references the wrong variable.  Since it looks at `root`, and completely ignores the parameter `node`, every call to `height` will be the same and the recursion, once started, will never end.

Replace all references to `root` with `node` in `height`.

```
if (node == nullptr) 
    return 0;
int leftside = height(node->left);
int rightside = height(node->right);
```

And a few unrelated things:

`height` could be declared `const`, or made a static member of `BinaryTree`, or moved into the `Node` class.

You have a constructor for `TreeNode`, which should handle initializing all of the members of the class.  When you allocate or add a node you should just have the one line `wherever = new TreeNode(key);`.  (And what's the difference between `theData` and `value`?  Do you need to distinct fields for these?)

The `BinaryTree *tree` in `main` can just be an object, and does not need to be dynamically allocated (`BinaryTree tree;`, then change all the `tree->` to `tree.`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I will make the changes now and hopefully get it working

Comment: I made the changes to the height() method; changed root to node etc. so I no longer get a stack overflow error, although the method keeps returning 0 in console. Does the other implementation in height() look correct to you?

Comment: @craig2020 The base case (root == NULL) returns 0, and you never add anything to it when you call it recursively, so it can't return anything other than 0.